# Handling Unique Validation with Status Accepted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am making Rails backend api for mobile app, and want to validate unique record with accepted status code.

@Why?

When I save entries from mobile app, I want to avoid saving duplicate records in Rails, but I also want to send "accepted status code" from Rails to mobile app instead of error status not to stop running bulk saving from mobile.

Model

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :uuid, uniqueness: true
end
```

Controllers

```
  def create

    # Check if the same record already exists
    entry = Entry.find_by(uuid: entry_params[:uuid])

    if entry.present?
      render json: {errors: {message: 'The same uuid already exists.'}}, status: :accepted
      return
    end

    entry             = Entry.new
    entry.attributes  = entry_params

    if entry.save
      render json: entry, status: :created
    else
      render json: entry.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

The above code works as I want, but I am wondering if I can use validations of Rails properly instead.

This is what I tried, but couldn't get unique uuid error unfortunately. Is there any better way to handle this situation?

ApplicationController

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique, with: :record_not_unique

    def record_not_unique
      render json: {errors: {message: 'Record not unique.'}}, status: :accepted
    end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The uniqueness **validation will not raise an exception**. It just sets the `errors` object on the validated `entry` record and prevents saving it. You have two options in principle:

- Get rid of the uniqueness validation in your model, and set up a UNIQUE constraint on the column in the underlying database table. Then, the `save` call would raise the `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` exception triggered by the database. And then you indeed should be able to `rescue_from` it the way you posted.
- Do without exceptions (dump `rescue_from`) and leave the uniqueness validation in place and process the `errors` manually in your controller, something along the lines of:

  ```
  def create      
    entry = Entry.new(entry_params)

    if entry.save
      render json: entry, status: :created
    elsif entry.errors.count == 1 && entry.errors[:uuid].first == "has already been taken"
      render json: {errors: {message: 'The same uuid already exists.'}}, status: :accepted
    else
      render json: entry.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to use `rescue_from` because a triggered exception will effectively fail-fast your request.  You should cache/log these results of successes/failures (non-uniques) instead.

You can send status 201 when a record has been created, and send status 202 when duplicate record was determined.  Bucket each status and at the end of the batch, execute any post-processing at the end.